# Build error in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am creating an android apps using phonegap. After build 3 apps(windows,hp,i) is builded correctly other three(ios,android,bb) has errors. I am creating this app with help of [this tutorial](http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/). Could anyone please tell me why this is showing error. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have told that you followed [this tutorial](http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/). I have also created a push notification app by this tutorial. Try without using "***Plugin Installation for PhoneGap Build" part. Dont add plugin into xml then try.

Comment: Thanx for help. I am trying.

Answer (score 0):

I think because you didn't set the Tokens or Key to send a push notifictation, Android and Apple need to provide you with a key to send push notifications. In the future please be more specific, we can't see what the real error is when you don't even provide a error message or code.

Comment: phone gap doesn't give me any error. And i have created and uploaded the key.When i am not including the plugin on the xml file it builds successfully. I am using push plugin.

Comment: Is there any other site to create apps like phonegap.

Comment: Yes, you could use AppVerse.